# C# won't allow me to add event handler to a button into a form class

Tags: c#, event-handling

This is a C# web form project I am starting with after a long time away from IDE coding...

I am trying to make a simple custom dialog box class. This is my code.

```
public static class Dialogo
{
        public static int show ()
        {
            Form dialogo = new Form();

            dialogo.Width = 300;
            dialogo.Height = 300;

            Button btnSim = new Button() { Text = "Sim", Left = 30, Width = 100 };
            Button btnNao = new Button() { Text = "Não", Left = 150, Width = 100 };

            dialogo.Controls.Add(btnSim);
            dialogo.Controls.Add(btnNao);
            dialogo.ShowDialog();

            // the following two lines are the problematic ones
            btnSim += new EventHandler(btnSim_Click);
            btnNao += new EventHandler(btnNao_Click);

            return -1;
        }
}
```

It's underlining the text within parenthesis and the message says:

**The name btnSim_Click' does not exist in the current context**

The problem is that I tried to add the following in my code but it doesn't let me put it anywhere (it always says that is something wrong):

```
private int btnNao_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return 0;
}

private int btnSim_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return 1;
}
```

My objective is that each of the both buttons btnSim and btnNao return a different value (say 1 and 0).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want to do `btnSim.click +=` and then the methode have to return void and not int. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `dialogo.ShowDialog();`  is modal, so the code under it doesn't run until the form is closed, which means your event handlers weren't subscribed at the time the form was showing.  Also, events don't return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventHandler` is a delegate for a method that returns `void`.
Your methods return `int`.

Try something like this:

```
 public static int show()
    {
        int returnValue = -1;

        using (Form dialogo = new Form())
        {
            dialogo.Width = 300;
            dialogo.Height = 300;

            Button btnSim = new Button() { Text = "Sim", Left = 30, Width = 100 };
            Button btnNao = new Button() { Text = "Não", Left = 150, Width = 100 };

            dialogo.Controls.Add(btnSim);
            dialogo.Controls.Add(btnNao);

            btnSim.Click += (s, e) => { returnValue = 0; dialogo.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; };
            btnNao.Click += (s, e) => { returnValue = 1; dialogo.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; };
            dialogo.Disposed += (s, e) =>
            {
                btnSim?.Dispose();
                btnSim = null;

                btnNao?.Dispose();
                btnNao = null;
            };

            dialogo.ShowDialog();
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```